# The Federation Service could not authorize token issuance for caller 'DOMAIN\Account'

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, adfs2.0, adfs3.0, adfs2.1

I am using ADFS in Windows Server 2012 with SAML 2.0 to implement SSO for an MVC application. I started to get this error which I am unable to find a way to solve. What am I doing wrong?

```
The Federation Service could not authorize token issuance for caller 'xxx\xxxx
'. The caller is not authorized to request a token for the relying party 'https://example.com/SampleMvcApplication/AuthServices'. Please see event 501 with the same instance id for caller identity. 

Additional Data 
Instance id: xyz 
Relying party: https://example.com/SampleMvcApplication/AuthServices 
Exception details: 
Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.IssuancePipeline.CallerAuthorizationException: MSIS5007: The caller authorization failed for caller identity System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity for relying party trust https://example.com/SampleMvcApplication/AuthServices.
   at System.IdentityModel.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.IdentityModel.TypedAsyncResult`1.End(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.IdentityModel.SecurityTokenService.EndIssue(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.Issue(IssueRequest issueRequest)
   at Microsoft.IdentityServer.Service.SamlProtocol.SamlProtocolService.ProcessRequest(Message requestMessage) 
User Action 
Use the AD FS Management snap-in to ensure that the caller is authorized to request a token for the relying party.
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Relying Party Trust (RPT) for this service provider (SP), take a look at the Issuance Authorization Rules tab.  You'll need at least one rule to issue the claim type *http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/permit* with a value of ***true*** and no claims issuing the claim type *http://schemas.microsoft.com/authorization/claims/deny* with a value of ***true***, though technically I don't believe any value is needed for either.  If all users are allowed to the front door of your SP, you can use the rule template under Add Rule called ***Permit All Users***.

Answer (score 1):

You need to permit that user for the relying party configured in ADFS.

ADFS management -> Relying party Trusts -> Right click your relying party -> Edit claim rules -> Issuance Authorization Rules -> Add Rule -> Permit access to all users.